# How to add pdf file for appendix in XeLaTeX

Tags: color, pdfpages

I am writing a progress report in LaTeX with XeLaTeX compiler. I have several pdf files to add to my Appendix. I used `\usepackage{pdfpages}` to add. When I compile I got an error like

> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package
>   xcolor.

I used color package `\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}`

Here the command for appendix

```
\appendix
\section{Ape}
\includepdf{C:/Users/Figurado/Desktop/Latex/Survey.pdf}
```

Please help to overcome this problem.

Comment: Can you provide a [complete-but-small example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the problem please?

Answer (score 3):

Package `pdfpages` loads `eso-pic`, which loads `xcolor` without option. So either you load `xcolor` with options *before* `pdfpages`, or you don't load it at all and add to the preamble:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}
```

or you add these options  to the document class options.

Comment: I used like this \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}. How can I modify that?

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,table,xcdraw]{article}`. The class will propose the unknown options to the loaded packages until one of them accepts one of the options.

Comment: Yes. It works. When I try to make heading \section{Appendix} and then print the pdf. It create an empty page having Appendix title and   then print the pdf file. Can I solve it?

Comment: Did you use the `\appendix` command? Which document class do you use?

Comment: Yes. I did. I used \appendix and \section{Appendix.} I used article class